# beautifulsoup - filter text of anchor tag is not working when there is img tag in front of text

Tags: html, python-3.x, regex, beautifulsoup

I have the following html content :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """<a href="http://app_url1" >install app xyz</a>
<a href="http://app_url2" ><img src="/path.jpg">install app xyz</a>
<a href="http://app_url3" >install app aaa</a>
<a href="http://app_url4">install app aaa</a>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.findAll("a", text=re.compile("xyz$")))
```

I want to filter the anchor tag texts that end with a given regex pattern (like xyz here)? I am looking to pass a regex pattern to findAll instead of extra iteration of all anchor tags. But I am getting output only one anchor tag as

```
<a href="http://app_url1">install app xyz</a>
```

The other anchor tag which has img in front of text is getting ignored

expected output:

```
<a href="http://app_url1" >install app xyz</a>
<a href="http://app_url2" ><img src="/path.jpg">install app xyz</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS selector `select` instead of extra iteration of all anchor tags.
**Example**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """<a href="http://app_url1" >install app xyz</a>
<a href="http://app_url2" ><img src="/path.jpg">install app xyz</a>
<a href="http://app_url3" >install app aaa</a>
<a href="http://app_url4">install app aaa</a>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.select('a:contains("xyz")'))
```

**Output will be**:

```
[<a href="http://app_url1">install app xyz</a>, <a href="http://app_url2"><img src="/path.jpg"/>install app xyz</a>]
```

For getting `href` content from the list of the above output:

```
anchors = soup.select('a:contains("xyz")')
href = [i['href'] for i in anchors]
print(href)
```

Output will be:

```
['http://app_url1', 'http://app_url2']
```

Comment: Thanks Humayun, How to get href content from the list of the above output. eg: I need my output as [http://app_url1,  http://app_url2] after filtering with select statement

Answer (score 1):

Filter by only `text=re.compile("xyz$")` then use  `.parent`

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """<a href="http://app_url1" >install app xyz</a>
<a href="http://app_url2" ><img src="/path.jpg">install app xyz</a>
<a href="http://app_url3" >install app aaa</a>
<a href="http://app_url4">install app aaa</a>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
result = [el.parent for el in soup.findAll(text=re.compile("xyz$"))]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[<a href="http://app_url1">install app xyz</a>, <a href="http://app_url2"><img src="/path.jpg"/>install app xyz</a>]
```